# Foreign key references invalid column error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to run this query but SQL -erver stopped me with this error:

> Foreign key 'FK__food__groupid__3F115E1A' references invalid column 'groupid' in referenced table 'sub'.

This is my query:

```
create table menu
(
    valedid int primary key not null,
    name nvarchar(50) not null,
)

create table sub
(
    qroupid int primary key not null,
    groupname nvarchar(50) not null,
    valedid int not null,

    foreign key(valedid) references menu (valedid),
)

create table food
(
    foodid int primary key not null,
    radif int identity(1,1) not null,
    qeymat int not null,
    name nvarchar(100) not null,
    groupid int not null, 

    foreign key(groupid) references sub(groupid),
)
```

Comment: `sub`'s primary key column is `qroupid` with a `q` - not `groupid` with a `g` .....

Answer (score 1):

You create the column with name qroupid  and not groupid in table sub